# setting configuration file without @ngModule

Tags: typescript, configuration, config, ng-modules, configserver

I'm trying to move my component variables to a configuration file. I generated the service but I need to add it to a @ngModule in app.module.ts
I'm using the recent angular, is there a way to achieve this without using the @ngModule provider

I have generated my service and created a configuration file. I need helping connecting my configuration file to my components

Comment: Finally made the code work. I import my service and added provider to @component and it worked fine.